# Do we really need Automapper?

Tags: automapper

I was learning AutoMapper and understand its use for object to object mapping. But now EFCodeFirst,dapper and Petpoco all cools stuff are there which will allow us to use our POCO directly  with database?

So can anybody let me know why we still need automapper?

Thanks in advance

Best Regards,
Jalpesh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I usually use Automapper to map Domain models to view mdoels.  If doing DDD it is often suggested that it's not a great idea to use your Domain models in you views - views often have a different set of concerns to the domain.

For example, you may have a User model in your domain:

```
public class User
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string EmailAddress {get;set;}
  public string FirstName {get;set;}
  public string Surname {get;set;}
  public string HashedPassword {get;set;}
  public string EyeColour {get;set;}
}
```

And you may have a User summary page which shows a subset of these items:

```
public class UserSummary
{
  public string EmailAddress {get;set;}
  public string Surname {get;set;}
}
```

You could use the UserSummary class on the view, but you would probably fetch the domain user model from the db.  In this case you could use Automapper to map the Domain.User to the ViewModel.UserSummary

```
var user = _repository.Get(1);
var viewmodel = Automapper.Map<Domain.User, ViewModel.UserSummary>(user);
return View(viewmodel);
```

Comment: will it have  any performance overhead as I am planning it as very big site?

Comment: I honestly don't think it will cause a problem. I have used on large sites no problem. Actually setting up the maps may take some time (Mapper.CreateMap call) and should be done once on application start. There's analysis on performance of Automapper here: http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/08/05/analyzing-automapper-performance/

Comment: There may be a performance penalty if your View is doing paging or filtering. Automapper doesn't work with IQueryable objects, so your query will execute when mapping. If you use a grid such as Telerik, it will apply its filtering an sorting when you return the viewdata, after the mapping. You'll want to look into Projection to get around this issue.